# How to plug into Mac Air a 4pin Microphone with 4pin headphones through a splitter?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone

I have a 4 pin mini-jack headphones and 4 pin mini jack microphone (BOYA). I want to plug them into the Mac Air but I have a 2x3 pin to 4 pin splitter and it seems that it doesn't work - the computer doesn't see the microphone. What should be the splitter to plug it all at a time? I thought 2x4 pin(f) -> 4 pin(m) but I haven't been able to find one. Will a 4 pin -> 3 pin adapter work if I plug the microphone to it and then plug it into my splitter together with headphones? What adapters or splitters should I purchase to make it work?

Update:

The microphone works well when I plug it into the headphones multi hole directly but doesn't when I plug it into the splitter with headphones.
Two 4 pin headsets work well through a splitter that I have (output is 4 pin, but I don't know what is there at the inputs). Microfone and headset don't work with this splitter.

Update-2:

My adapter OMTP - CTIA is here ([link](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32817429531.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.76c233edbls6s4)) and I tried to plug the microphone in different ways, but unfortunately the MAC doesn't see it through the splitter.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably correct in assuming you need a 2x4 pin(f) -> 4 pin(m) adaptor. You have an adaptor that splits for a headphone and microphone. What you need is an adaptor that splits for two headsets. In other words, everything (headphone, microphone and Mac) is TRRS.

I was able to find TRRS Y adaptor/cables for purchase by searching Google for *TRRS Male to Dual TRRS Female*. For example, [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IKMSMWI) was the first link I encountered. The excerpt below was taken from [this link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FBBBWXW). This excerpt actually states for use with 4 pin mini jack microphones.

> Plus, allow you to connect one headphone, and one external 4-POLE TRRS microphone (NOT 3-pole TRS microphone) to Laptop, Tablet, PC computer or Smartphone into the 4-POLE 3.5mm jack at the same time.

Be aware there are two standards in use for TRRS. Basically, the difference is the sleeve and adjacent ring are reversed. See the image below.

[image]

You may need a converter which switches the ground (common) with the microphone. An example of a converter is shown below..

[image]

The above adaptor can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q8GLYW3).

> Note: If a adaptor is needed, then the adaptor should be placed either between the headphone and the splitter or between the splitter and the Mac.

Comment: Thank you David, and why the microphone works well when I plug it into the headphones multi hole directly but doesn't when I plug it into the splitter with headphones? The CTIA or OMTP are equal for the mac input?

Comment: Does this one cover my needs? https://www.aliexpress.com/i/33000785635.html

Comment: The thruth is that I have one splitter and two pairs of 4 pin headsets that works well on Mac. Can we say that it's the proper splitter and I only need for an adapter OMTP-CTIA?

Comment: With regards to the splitter offered by AliExpress: I would assume the jacks would be to close together to allow both the mic and headphone to be plugged in at the same time.